# Is it possible to declare global variables in Node-RED and use them on the node configuration?

Tags: node-red

Supposing that I'm receiving information from many devices with the MQTT protocol and the following diagram is a simplified version of the block of one device:

[image: device one]

So let's also suppose that all other devices have exactly the same diagram, except for the topic name that is going to change to `device2` for the second device, `device3` for the third device and so on, as follows:

[image: device two]

The problem is that I want a way of changing names inside the node's configuration without having to do it one by one. Like declaring a global variable that can be used not just in the function but in the nodes themselves. For example, the last picture could use something like: `MYVARIABLE_temperatureA` and `MYVARIABLE_temperatureB` as topics.

So, is it possible to do something like this using the Node-RED? Or the solution lies just in creating a customized node that has a specific field for placing values?

Answer (score 4):

Not using the global context, but you can use environment variables using the following syntax:

```
$(ENV_VAR_NAME)
```

So you could prefix the configuration variables with a Environment variable then change those to update the nodes (with a restart of Node-RED)

Comment: I see... But where can I add a value to the variable ENV_VAR_NAME?

Comment: Depends what node-red is running, but you can set them on the cmd line before starting node-red

Comment: Do you mean setting as a system variable on a terminal before starting the Node-RED? Could you give me more details? I tried setting system variables but it didn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this helps: https://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions#global-context

**Global context**

There is also a global context available that is shared by, and accessible to all nodes. For example to make the variable foo available globally across the canvas:

```
global.set("foo","bar");  // this is now available to other nodes
```

And can then be read using .get

```
var myfoo = global.get("foo");  // this should now be "bar"
```

Comment: As discussed in the other answer the global context is not useful for this question

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but the current method proviced be Nick O'Leary in the node-red google group is as follows:

> 1. Edit your node-red settings file (/home/pi/.node-red/settings.js) and add the following (above the module.exports lines):
>
>    process.env.HOSTNAME = require('os').hostname();
> 2. restart Node-RED. Et Voila - $(HOSTNAME) now works.
>
> You can set any env var you want under the `process.env` object.

Lets say you wanted to add FOO and set it to 'just another bar', you would add the following:
    process.env.FOO = 'just another bar';
and you can now use it.

Comment: `HOSTNAME` is a special case as for some reason NodeJS removes this from the list of environment variables exposed at start up. Setting anything else via the `settings.js` file is not required and actually harder to do in PaaS environments

Comment: You can use this method to add any variable. Add (above the module.exports lines): <process.env.SECRETMSG = 'Nick and Dave are awsome!';<then add  <env:process.env <to the <    functionGlobalContext: <and you can then access a function node with: var env = global.get('env');
msg.payload = env.SECRETMSG;
return msg;